Who exactly is Fake Crash?
In Crash Bandicoot: Warped and also in N. Sane Trilogy you can see this weird (and fake) version of Crash dancing outside of some levels. He even became a playable character then in Crash Team Racing.
But who exactly is "Fake" Crash? Does he have a backstory, or maybe a real name?

According to Crash Bandicoot wiki:

In the series, there is no common depiction of Fake Crash's origins. It's implied in Crash Bandicoot 2: N-Tranced that Fake Crash was accidentally created after N. Tropy and N. Trance tried to abduct Crash Bandicoot by sucking him into a portal. As Aku Aku pulls Crash out, Fake Crash appears out of nowhere at N. Tropy and N. Trance's side of the portal, with them believing they captured Crash.

We all remember Fake Crash in the games, but his first appearance was in a Japanese commercial:



where a comparison was made between the original Crash (ホンモノ) and the fake one/the imposter (ニセモノ):

Regarding his name, Fake Crash is not known to have one, although on November 2020 the official Crash Bandicoot: On the Run Twitter account was renamed to Trash Bandicoot: On the Run, suggesting that Fake Crash had taken over the account:

He also was referring to himself as "Trash Bandicoot", maybe suggesting that that's his real name:

